# Java class file runs in project but not outside of project in IntelliJ

Tags: java

I just had a quiz where we were supposed to make a Hospital class with some given criteria and then instantiate a hospital class in HospitalTester driver class...I completed the assignment without much issue in IntelliJ and it ran fine.

Then I did what I always do, I copy the java file that I am going to submit, `HospitalTester.java` out of the project folder and then submit it on its own (professor doesn't want us to submit projects, just individual java files).

I thought I was done and everything was fine, but to my horror I got an email today saying that only 1 person in the class got a 100/100. I went to check what I submitted and when I run it, nothing happens...

All of my code is below and it worked just fine when I opened it up as a project that I saved under as "Quiz 1", but doesn't run when I remove it from the src folder in the project folder.

Why did this happen?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HospitalTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Construct new hospital instance
        Hospital hospital = new Hospital(
                "Grey-Sloan Memorial",
                10,
                150000.79,
                2450896.50);


        // Asks for keyboard prompt for hospital information.
        hospital.setName();
        hospital.setNumberOfDoctors();
        hospital.setAvgDoctorSalary();
        hospital.setTotalGrossIncome();


        //Creates a new String variable to print toString() method out from
        String sys;
        sys = hospital.toString();
        System.out.print(sys);

        // Provides percent of doctor salary compared to Total Gross Income
        hospital.percentDoctors();
    }

}


class Hospital {
    String name;
    private int number_doctors;
    private double avg_salary_doctors;
    private double total_gross_income;


    // Hospital Constructor
    public Hospital(String name, int number_doctors, double avg_salary_doctors, double total_gross_income) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number_doctors = number_doctors;
        this.avg_salary_doctors = avg_salary_doctors;
        this.total_gross_income = total_gross_income;
    }

    // Get methods to return hospital name, number of doctors, avg doctor salary, and total gross income of hospital.
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumberOfDoctors() {
        return number_doctors;
    }

    public double getAvgDoctorSalary() {
        return avg_salary_doctors;
    }

    public double getTotalGrossIncome() {
        return total_gross_income;
    }

    //Set methods to change hospital name, number of doctors, avg doctor salary, and total income of hospital varaibles.

    public void setName() {
        System.out.print("Enter a new name for the hospital: \n");
        this.name = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    }

    public void setNumberOfDoctors() {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of doctors working at the hospital: \n");
        this.number_doctors = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    }

    public void setAvgDoctorSalary() {
        System.out.print("Enter the average doctor salary: \n");
        this.avg_salary_doctors = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
    }

    public void setTotalGrossIncome() {
        System.out.print("Enter the total gross income that the hospital makes: \n");
        this.total_gross_income = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
    }

    // Calculates total doctors salary: (Number of doctors * avg salary of doctor) / Total Gross Income
    public void percentDoctors() {
        double percent, percent_converted;
        String percent_converted_rounded;
        percent = (number_doctors * avg_salary_doctors) / total_gross_income;
        percent_converted = percent * 100;

        // Round off to two decimal places.
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
        percent_converted_rounded = df.format(percent_converted);

        System.out.print("Doctor salary as a percent of total gross income = " + percent_converted_rounded + "% \n");


    }


    public String toString() {


        //Provide formatting to Doctor salary and hospital income financial numbers.
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
        String hospital_income_format, avg_salary_doctors_format;
        hospital_income_format = df.format(total_gross_income);
        avg_salary_doctors_format = df.format(avg_salary_doctors);


        return "Name = " + name
                + "\nNumber of Doctors = " + number_doctors + " doctors " +
                "\nAverage Doctor Salary = $" + avg_salary_doctors_format +
                "\nHospital Income = $" + hospital_income_format + "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot run a .java class. You need to compile it first, get a .class file and then you can run it.

Comment: @Atizs how come I can run a .java class like this in a project? What changes?

Comment: If you check in your Intellij project folder, you will see class map. When you do "run", Intellij first compiles the .java files you wrote into .class files and then executes them. Project Folder/out/production     This is where the class files are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied your code in a Java file called `HospitalTester.java`

I run `javac HospitalTester.java`

I run `java HospitalTester`

The scanner starts:

```
Enter a new name for the hospital:
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: OH, you need a second command to run the HospitalTester class lol. Okay thanks, that makes sense. I hope my teacher knew this lol

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just copied the code and ran it using javac command (saving it as java file in a random folder) and it works fine for me. Did you try executing it using javac or the IDE itself?

Comment: It doesn't give  me an option to run it in the IDE like it normally does (green arrow). I tried to use the terminal in the IDE and outside of the IDE with `javac HospitalTester.java` and nothing happened

Comment: @EvanKim probably you are not in "java project context"

Comment: I just posted a screenshot. Did you get any error message? if you are on windows, check the Java environment variable .

Comment: oh, I didn't realize after `javac HospitalTester.java` you have to then input a second command `java HospitalTester` lol